# Chartboost "no_host_activity" Corona Native

Tags: android, native, coronasdk, chartboost

I integrated chartboost sdk according to [instruction](https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/child_article/android#orient) but i got `no_host_activity` error when i call `Chartboost.showInterstitial` .

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem by adding `Chartboost.onStart(activity);`
before calling `Chartboost.showInterstitial`